# Help with determining the open circuit voltage

Tags: voltage, math, electrical, circuits

[image: A circuit with dependent and independent sources]

Can someone go through why Vxy= -84mV?
Given the values off VB=180mv 
                     R1=22ohms
                     R2=68ohms
                     R3=150 ohms.
Many thanks

Comment: Homework must have an attempt at a solution, or it is off topic.

Comment: This is a pretty easy problem.  Where are you stuck?  What have you tried?  What result do you  get?

Comment: I tried to get a value for V1, and then used KCL to get I2 and then did I2*R2. Then that voltage will be equal to Vxy?

Comment: What result did you get for I2 and for V1?  Add the equations you used to your question along with the results and we'll be able to spot your mistake.

Comment: Vb-V1-5V1=0.... VB=6V1.... 0.18/6=V1 = 0.03V.... Then V1/R1 +5V1/R3=I2.

Comment: OK, let's start with the basics.  You said you are looking for the open circuit voltage, so what is Ix?  Then what's the voltage across R3? Then what can you do to find VA and V1?  VB-V1-VA=0 is the correct application of KVL in this case, not VB-V1-5V1=0.

Comment: Wouldn't Ix be 0 as it an open loop?

Comment: Yes.  Ix is zero.  So calculate Va.  Since Ix is zero R1 and R2 have the same current, which is equal to VB divided by what?